# Toggle between column selection and regular selection in Sublime Text 2

Tags: text-editors, textmate, text-editing, sublime-text-2

In Textmate, I can make a regular multiline selection using the keyboard and switch to column selection mode by pressing the `alt` (⌥) key.

I have not found a similar way of doing this in Sublime Text 2. I can however make a column selection by pressing the `alt` key and using the mouse. Is there a way of doing this with just the keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is [in the documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html): it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>direction</kbd>.

Do not start with a previous selection, though, as the outcome is a bit unpredictable.

Comment: I had already read that document. I don't think there is any way to toggle between selection modes though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, I think you are right.